# In python: How can I extract the maximum value in the third column , and return the value in fourth column?

Tags: python, nlp

I have the data like this :

```
    0 1 251 TrCP
    0 2 68 TrCP
    0 3 61 TrCP
    0 4 69 TrCP
    0 5 70 TrCP
    0 6 75 TrCP
    0 7 63 TrCP
    0 8 57 TrCP
    0 9 96 TrCP
    0 10 266 TrCP
    ........
    0 2827 62 TrNAP
    1 1 67 TrCP
    1 2 84 TrCP
    1 3 159 TrCP
    1 4 121 TrCP
    1 5 80 TrCP
    1 6 68 TrCP
    1 7 148 TrCP
    1 8 78 TrCP
    1 9 71 TrCP
    1 10 67 TrCP
    ........
    1 2827 76 TrNAP
    .
    .
    .
    2828 1 62 TrCP
```

In the first column, I have number from 0 - 2828.
For each number in 0-2828
I wanna extract the last column (TrCP for example) according to the value in third column.
For example, in the first column ='0', the max value in third column is '266', I wanna return the output: TrCP.

Comment: Show what you have tried please.

Comment: how and where are the above mentioned data stored?

Comment: this is the output from last step actually, I tried to store it in this way: ['0 1 251 TrCP', '0 2 68 TrCP',...] but don't know how to process it next, so i actually have no idea how to save it for further steps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your data is stored, but the most ubiquitous solution is as follows:

```
my_array= [251, 68, 61, 69, 70, 75...]
whoa_a_wild_array = ['TrCP','TrCP','TrCP','TrCP',...]
whoa_a_wild_array[np.argmax(x)]
```

Here `np.argmax()` returns the index of the max value. We can then access that index in our other array/vector/list/etc. Tadaa!

If you are using pandas the code is quite similar:

```
df['4th_column'].values[df['3rd_column'].argmax()]]
```

the `.values` ensures that you actually pull the desired index and not a misordered label (ie if your dataframe's index is numbered and you don't wish to access that.)

Comment: thanks for helping, it is just I have the first column with different value, so when first column the value is '0', i need to find the max value, when first column the value is '1', I need to find the max value again, so do to all the different numbers in first column

Comment: don't know if i explained myself properly, sorry

Comment: are you using pandas? it will make things easier if you are :P